# express remove prefixed URL to public folder

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Even though i have created static public folder in app.js

when i navigate to "http://localhost:3000/calenders/add" and i don't get any  styles which is in public folder. because express has added "calenders/add/" to the public folder URL.

So it looks like "http://localhost:3000/calenders/add/content_inside_public".

But the correct URL should be "http://localhost:3000/content_inside_public"

Navigate to app index works fine and load all the styles.

Of course i can set static path in app.js like this

```
app.use('/calenders/add',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

but it's not practical if i have many routes in my app.

I believe this is happening because i have a separated folder called partials inside the view directory to store headers,footers and navigation bar, so that i can include them any where in the app easily without writing same html code again and again.

This is how i included them in calender/add.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<% include ../partials/head.ejs %>
<body>
<!-- Side Navbar -->
<% include ../partials/side_nav.ejs %>

<div class="page">
    <!-- navbar-->
    <% include ../partials/header.ejs %>


    <% include ../partials/footer.ejs %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how i have access the folders and style-sheets inside the public directory in headers.ejs and footers.ejs

```
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/grasp_mobile_progress_circle-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

This is my project structure.

```
/public
     /css
     /js
     /vendor
     .......
/routes
    calendars.js
    control_panel.js
    index.js
/views
    /calendars
         add.ejs
    /control_panel
         index.ejs
         calendars.ejs
    /partials
         header.ejs
         footer.ejs
         ......
    index.ejs
```

Here is the app.js

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/control_panel', control_panel);
app.use('/calenders', calenders);
```

Calendars.js

```
router.get('/add', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('calenders/add', { title: 'Express' });

});
```

control_panel.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('control_panel/index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with express,

this is because in **/calenders/add**, src of `<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>` will resolve to http://localhost:3000/calenders/add/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js,

because `vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js` is a relative path.

what you need is to change the url to this:

```
<script src="/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/grasp_mobile_progress_circle-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes u r correct. Problem solved..! Thank you very much